# Use ViewAnimator to slide out discarded old view, and slide in new view

Tags: android

Currently, I have a `ViewAnimator`, which used to hold the green color chart on the top

```
    this.chartViewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)chartContainer.findViewById(R.id.chart_view_animator);        
    this.chartViewAnimator.setAnimateFirstView(true);
    Animation slideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    Animation slideOutRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    int configMediumAnimTime = 2000;
    slideInLeft.setDuration(configMediumAnimTime);
    slideOutRight.setDuration(configMediumAnimTime);
    this.chartViewAnimator.setInAnimation(slideInLeft);
    this.chartViewAnimator.setOutAnimation(slideOutRight);
```

[image]

Now, I want to change the duration of the top chart. I'm expecting

- An animation to slide out old green chart, and discard it forever (Don't keep in memory).
- An animation to slide in new red chart.

[image]

I use the following code.

```
// Discard old chart. I'm expecting view animator will perform slide out animation.
chartViewAnimator.removeAllViews();
// I expect view animator will perform slide in animation.
chartViewAnimator.addView(graphicalView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

**However, there isn't any animation at all.**

First, I expect while discarding old view via `removeAllViews`, `ViewAnimator` will perform slide out animation for me. I'm also expecting `ViewAnimator` will perform slide in animation, when the new red chart is added.

Seem like I were wrong. Is there any steps I had missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all old views ever time when inserting new view, will not trigger any animation. There should be at least 2 views within `ViewAnimator`, in order to observe slide in and slide out effect.

```
    chartViewAnimator.addView(graphicalView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    // Ensure there is always at least 2 views.
    if (chartViewAnimator.getChildCount() >= 3) {
        chartViewAnimator.removeViewAt(0);
    }
    chartViewAnimator.setDisplayedChild(chartViewAnimator.getChildCount() - 1);
```